# Default timeout values for Kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes

I was going through the docs and found out the custom timeout configurations: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-timeouts

But it doesn't say if there are any defaults and what are the values. Is it documented somewhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that NGINX Ingress Controller is open source, the safest bet would be looking at the repository. I believe the default values can be found in [internal/ingress/controller/config/config.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/48601bcd0e8fa1e22726e517fe70fc268a900fd4/internal/ingress/controller/config/config.go#L745).

Answer (score 2):

Default value should be 60 seconds. This is the default socket timeout value.